# Namespace is different for derived types in generated xml form xmlbean

Tags: xml, xmlbeans

Generated xml form schema is well formed.

Like:

```
<tns:SCommand xmlns:tns="https/bla/bla/command" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
   <tns:Command xsi:type="tns:MyCommand">
```

While I construction XML form Java code(XMLbeans) the namespace for derived type is different

Ex:

```
CommandType  ct = MyCommand.Factory.newInstance();
```

The xml is

```
<myc:Command xsi:type="MyCommand" xmlns:myc="https/bla/bla/command">
```

The name space is miss matching with schema after generating XML form xmlbeans. the prefix is different and uri is adding. How to resolve this?